# Como faço para que um sublinhado fique com um tamanho definido?

Tags: html, css

Tentei deixar sublinhado com tamanho definido usando `<font style=" text-decoration:underline 3px;>`, mas, infelizmente, não funciona.

Conseguir deixar o sublinhado com tamanho definido com `<font style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;">`, porém fica um espaço entre o sublinhado e a palavra.

Tentei no CSS `{display:inline-block; borderborder-bottom: 3px solid #000000;line-height: 25px;}` e também troquei `"inline-block"` por `"block"` e deu certo somente no desktop. Não fica espaço entre o sublinhado e a palavra. No celular, fica uma linha enorme que vai muito além da palavra sublinhada.

Tentei somente inline e não tive esse problema no celular, porém apresenta o problema do  `<font style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;">` : fica espaço entre o sublinhado e a palavra, como se o `line-height` fosse inútil.

Tentei colocar valores sem ser px no `line-height`, tentei valores relativos: 0,85, 1 e 1,5, e continua a mesma coisa.

Já tentei também trocar `line-height` por `border-spacing` e `margin-bottom` e nada também.

Não sei mais o que fazer. Como resolvo esta questão?

Comment: Coloque um exemplo para ter ideia no que esta sendo realizado. Pegue um trecho do se código para expressar o seu contexto.

Comment: Vc quer alterar a espessura do sublinhado? Não entendi direito

Comment: Isso, quero aumentar a espessura, mas não consigo no text-decoration:underline. Quando uso outras coisas para aumentar a espessura, fica espaço entre a palavra e o sublinhado. Eu queria apenas aumentar a espessura do sublinhado, não quero espaço entre o sublinhado e a palavra.

Comment: Thiago, eu editei a pergunta. Talvez, agora você entenda melhor.

Comment: Se você quer aumentar a espessura (grossura) do sublinhado, acho interessante esclarecer isso na pergunta. Tamanho do sublinhado está muito vago. O que [pode] torna[r] a pergunta duplicata. A duplicata não menciona aumento de espessura do sublinhado padrão. Mas, dependendo de como vc for utilizar, você pode aproveitar boa parte das respostas de lá.